# workstation 7 and host-only no connectivity

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation, tcpip

I have a WinXP 32 host (IBM T400) with VWware workstation 7 (7.0.1 build-227600) and some guest OS (Win xp, NT, etc.)

I can ping from the host to guest OS and vice versa, but... every other "protocols" do not work at all. No http from host to guest, no CIFS, nothing, nothing, nothing.

Windows firewall is turned off, TCP/IP filer is turned off.

i re-installed VMware workstation, then the networking started working again, but, after some reboots... it stopped again.

Connectivity among guest OS... it works FINE.

Can not understand... problems exist just between host and guest. Host-only or NAT... it is the same.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if the ICS service (in windows services.) on the host is started - turn if off if it is.